# Reading and writing video files' contents

Tags: c#, php, file

If you want to read a video file's content and copy it to another file, it is simple:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("a.wmv");
string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("b.wmv");
sw.Write(contents);
```

but the problem is that by doing that c# will change some chars like "²uژ" to something else.
I tried to do this with php like this:

```
$a = file_get_contents("a.wmv");
file_put_contents("b.wmv",$a);
```

It worked! What should I do with that c# codes? & Of course I what to do some changes in video files' contents and put some passwords in it.

Comment: Why don't you just use a copy method ?

Comment: @Marged As I said I want to do some changes in contents. Actually I want to put users' passwords in somewhere in that content and encode it; So when user want to see that movie again, he must enter his pass.

Comment: Really ? I only see read and write

Comment: @Marged It is just beginning of my project. I want to first know how to read and write video contents after that I will do what I want.

Comment: I would suggest you keep the authorization part outside the contents of the video.

Comment: @Also, look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456(v=vs.110).aspx). You need to specify a correct encoding in order to read the file properly.

Comment: @MohsenNemati In your app! If you just put some passwords in a video file, there's no way, it will act as a security solution. Apart from that, it might even corrupt the file.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Thanks. But if I don't change the content the file can be opened by user. The app is not important , that file is important. I search HOW TO HIDDEN FILES but I just found something like what windows does. That is not proper.

Comment: @MohsenNemati Oh.. I understand... Then you better use a BinaryReader/BinaryWriter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Sorry for this delay! I did the binary read & write like this  `BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(@"c:\wamp\www\b.wmv", FileMode.Open));

             char[] s = br.ReadChars(1000);
             
             BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(@"c:\mydata.txt", FileMode.Create));
             bw.Write(s);`but still changes some chars like &² to &�